# Restore from wastebasket shortcut?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for GNOME desktop to restore a file which has been sent to wastebasket? 
I did this on windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, I just wonder if someone uses something similar on Linux?

Comment: Does ctrl-z work?

Comment: @Kevin nope, doesn't work